# Closed Subsets on Normal Spaces

Tags: general-topology, normal-subgroups

Show that every closed subset of a normal space X space is normal?

What is a good approach to this problem?

Comment: For a start,  if  $Y=\bar Y\subset X$ and $A, B$ are closed subsets of the subspace $Y$ then $A,B$ are closed in $X.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y=\bar Y\subset X$ and $A,B \subset Y $ disjoint closed sets. Then $A$ and $B$ are closed in $X$. Since $X$ is normal, $\exists U,V \subset X$ open sets such that $A \subset U$, $B \subset V$ and $U \cap V $=$\emptyset$.

What can you say about $U´=U \cap Y$ and $V´=V \cap Y$?